# determine if path is a file or just a directory - when file doesn't exist yet

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have reviewed the stackoverflow questions that are pertinent to my situation.
They don't answer a base question.
My application allows the user to type in a fully qualified path.  This path must be to a file.  The file cannot exist yet (they are saving a backup).  If you use the getattributes approach, it will trip the catch of the try/catch as the file is not found. (as it shouldn't be).  I need to catch if the user just put in a path to a directory, and if the path is to a file that the file doesn't exists.  I need to give directed feedback to the user if either case happens.  I am using C# with .NET framework of 4.5.2.

Thanks for any pointers.

Comment: "trip the catch of the try/catch" -- what does that mean? Is that a new feature? All you need to do is first confirm that the full path doesn't exist, then remove the last path segment and confirm that it's an existing directory. Can you find out if a file exists? Can you find out if a directory exists? Can you remove a path segment from a string? These are all trivial.

Comment: Here is a link to determine if the given input is a directory, file or non-existant:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.exists(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Didn't `File.Exists` and `Directory.Exists` methods help you out?

Comment: Thanks.  I have tried these, but the logic of my function was incorrect.  Fixed it and now it works.  Thanks.

Comment: Interesting.  I should have been much cleared with my question Ed Plunkett, and avoided slang.   I know I could edit the path string, but was wanting to use built in .NET to do it.  I didn't want to get into the game of out guessing the user entering data.  Sorry to bother you.

Comment: Why not simply check for the existence of a period after the last slash? Which is coincidentally what `Path.HasExtension` does ( https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.hasextension(v=vs.110).aspx ). // Though this solution still has issues, moreover the problem itself, because you can have directory names with `.` in them under Windows.

Comment: @KDecker you can also have a filename without an extension

Answer (score 2):

It is not mandatory for a file to have a file extension for it to be a valid file. Therefore, you can't rely on the path having a file extension to call it a file.

```
using System;

namespace FileFolder_46434099
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string incomingpath = @"C:\temp\3075";
            if (System.IO.Directory.Exists(incomingpath))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("path is a directory");
            }
            else if (System.IO.File.Exists(incomingpath))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("path is of a file");
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

In this instance... `C:\temp\3075` is actually a file, and the program returns it as such.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this and see if this is what you are looking for. I am assuming that user will enter extension of the file, as you mentioned user will enter fully qualified path.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter fully qualified path of the file to be accessed.");
        var eneteredPath = Console.ReadLine();
        var isItFile = Path.HasExtension(eneteredPath);
        if (isItFile)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Specified File exists = {File.Exists(eneteredPath)}");
        }
        else if(Directory.Exists(eneteredPath))
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Specified path is to a directory.");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

So I have a simple form with a txtInput, and a button:

```
using System.IO;

private void cmdCheck_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Directory.Exists(txtInput.Text))
        {
            // This is a directory, not a file.
        }
        else
        {
            try
            {
                if (File.Exists(txtInput.Text))
                {
                    var fileInfo = new FileInfo(txtInput.Text);

                    // File exists and now we have the information.  Alert the user.
                }
                else
                {
                    // File doesn't exist.  Do things.
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Trace.WriteLine(ex.Message, "ERROR");
            }
        }
    }
```

Does this suit your requirements?

Comment: blaze_125 brought up a good point about files not requiring an extension, so I modified my answer.

Answer (score 0):

This will helps you https://www.dotnetperls.com/path

Path. This path leads somewhere. It goes between trees and buildings. A cloud moves. Sunlight reaches the ground and our direction is clear.
With Path, a class in the .NET Framework, we have built-in methods. This class helps when handling file paths. It is part of System.IO.